# Gmail is consuming so much data in background

Tags: gmail, background-data

As you can see in the attached picture, Gmail has been consuming so much data, is this logical?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>(click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: May be possible if you enabled sync so the time and you have lots of mails with attachments too

Answer (score 0):

3.3 Go in background is kind of a lot

- You can reduce the number of days of messages to sync via Gmail app settings
- avoid building up a large number of messages in Gmail inbox archive them instead.

  Or you can use k-9 mail wich is really good!